# Preventing against HTML change in Firebug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

Let's assume I have a profile page where DropDown is shown and 1 Admin user can change role of different user.

Eg:

```
2 - Admin
3 - Member
```

Assume that `1` is for `SuperAdmin`. If we have a `DropDownList` in Asp.Net and bind it to datasource in code behind and then mysteriously try to change values in DropDownList and then submit the form we get exception due to `EventValidation`. However in Asp.Net MVC if we edit it would definitely because it embraces the web. Is there anything I could do to prevent this kind of cross cutting things in my web applications?

One of thing I could is to check when the form is posted to see if value posted is either 2 or 3 and if not display some message like "Are you trying to hack". Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: What on Earth does this statement mean: "However in Asp.Net MVC if we edit it would definitely because it embraces the web."?  If you're trying to imply that ASP.NET MVC doesn't provide a mechanism for server-side validation, then you're incorrect.  You should _always_ validate your input server-side against your application's business rules.  Even if somebody manually crafts a POST to your application and doesn't use your provided UI at all, you should check that what they're sending is valid.

Comment: @David: Checking on server is very easy by using ModelState.IsValid or Page.IsValid. But, Asp.Net webforms exception fires when we edit any values in dropdown which is very good. But in Asp.Net MVC due to lack of viewstate everything works. I think I need to validate for such things on server and take it very strictly but I just meant to say Asp.Net webforms provides a bit of added security. It may be due to ViewState.

Comment: What it provided was not "added security" by any means.  I see what you're saying, and essentially what that means was that the mechanisms at play in Web Forms tried to obscure the nature of the web from the developer.  But I would argue that this contributed to a culture of _less_ secure web applications rather than more secure ones.  The fundamental rule is that _all_ user input should be validated server-side.  _Always_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you mentioned (checking on server) IS the correct solution to prevent such hacks on web sites of any kind.

Using firebug is not the only option to "cheat" javascript based validation. It can also be done with any basic sniffer tools, such as fiddler, which can help a potential hacker to analyze the posted data to ur site, change it in a whatever way he wishes, and then to post it again, using the browser or his own networking tool.

I usually use both the validations (script and server side) in all the scenarios, while the client side validation's main purpose, in my opinion, is to prevent postbacks to server (which will annoy a normal user) when i can already tell on the client side, hes doing something wrong.

Such validations, however, can never be secure enough to guarrante the data is to be automaticlly trusted on server, as its too easy to modify javascript/ posted data, to override them.

**EDIT**

Following the resposne of UnhandleException:

In MVC specificly, you can use the Data Annotation attributes, to make the mvc engine render client side and server side validation for u

[This tutorial explains how do use the attributes validation in ur mvc apps](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on client side validation. Build a validator for each input. Place the set of validators on the server-side of your application. If there are validators on the client-side, make sure the same validators are implemented on the server-side as well.

Here inputs means URL-based parameters, Form-based parameters, Hidden fields, Cookies ets.